# How do I check if Batch Execution of SQL queries was successful or not in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing

To check a single query I use this

```
int a = statement.executeupdate();
if(a>0){
JoptionPane. showmessagediaglog(null, "Success");
else{
JoptionPane. showmessagediaglog(null, "Failed");
```

How do i do this with batch execution like `int a = statement.executebatch();`

This doesn't work of course, so is there a way?

Comment: Check the _array_ returned by `executeBatch()`; note spelling.

Comment: Could u please provide a code snippet bcuz I've tried that and failed. @trashgod

Answer (score 1):

executeBatch() returns an array of integers 
so you have to do:

```
int a[]= executeBatch();
```

And according to Java API: " if all commands execute successfully, returns an array of update counts. The int elements of the array that is returned are ordered to correspond to the commands in the batch, which are ordered according to the order in which they were added to the batch."

So, if the length of the array is equal to the length of updates you send on the batch, you can assume that it was successful. Or to make it more simple, and according to your example:

```
int a[] = statement.executeBatch();
   if(a.length>0){
      JoptionPane. showmessagediaglog(null, "Success");
   else{
      JoptionPane. showmessagediaglog(null, "Failed");
   }
```

You can also iterate on a[] values and sum the total number of rows affected and notify the user on the JOption dialog.